# Grid Stretch across the entire broswer.

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal

Good day everyone,

Im new to JavaScript & CSS. I need a JavaScript or CSS code to stretch out grid 5 x 2 along with pictures entirely across the browser width. For example look at this site http://www.cornell.edu/ middle of the page with grid layout. Zoom in / Out the grid will stretch out the entire browser width no matter what screen size. I understand if using CSS method background-image with the cover feature will width out the entire browser but not easy for user to edit who are not programmer. Here is information i got so far.

```
function resizeJqGridWidth(grid_id, div_id, width)
    {
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $('#' + grid_id).setGridWidth(width, true); //Back to original width
    $('#' + grid_id).setGridWidth($('#' + div_id).width(), true);//Resized to new width as per window
 }).trigger('resize');
  }
```

Any suggestion would be great.
Thanks alot!

Comment: Did you try `width: 100%` in CSS?

Comment: @MaihanNijat Yes I have. the 100% only maxing out the width for the template default. which is 1008px. I have each grid cell image set 333px width which required 1665 entire width. I did change the width of the grid set for 1666px but is not perfectly width set to the screen size.

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle would be great, in this case no one can be possibly knowing what your entire code looks like, what grid or framework are you using.

Comment: Here is my Codepen sandbox [ http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKGZab ]   as you see.  When you zoom out using Ctrl + or mouse scroll out the grid is following to the left instead doing the same feature middle of the page grid as [ http://www.cornell.edu/ ] . What am I missing to expand across the browser page even if zooming out.  Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using

```
box-sizing:border-box;
width: 20%;
```

On each image. This will allow 5 items across the screen and as log as the 5 physically total at least the max width of your content area this will fit perfectly and re-size as you shrink the screen..

Comment: Here is my codepen sandbox example                                                      [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwLRoj]

Comment: Code pen is 404 bud.

Comment: Your #overlayblock has width of 500%. Remove this and all will work as expected. Just may need an actual amount adding in rather than spurious percentages.

Comment: I did remove it and updated the code a little but still doesn't expand the grid across the browser depending on their width.  codepen.io/chaolu/pen/jWKEdB ]

Comment: Ahh i see. The width is 346px each which makes it over 1700 needed for browser. So each need to shrink right? If correct then you need to state max -width to container then nth-child to get the 6th element and clear it left.

Comment: Here is my real sandbox site. http://westcampusebxsfdc8zz.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/  as you can see it's not expand out across the page fully. Is there a JavaScript telling to resize it whenever width is define?

Comment: try, .overlayblock figcaption{top:195px} remove the inline image height unless you make them 195px, .overlayblock ul li{width:195px; height:195px}, Bit difficult to debug exactly but that should be a good start. If this is all going to be responsive then adjust the pixels as a percentage ratio instead.